# How to find the score function of $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$

Tags: calculus, statistics, statistical-inference

Given a Weibull model:

$\Pi_{i=1}^{n} \lambda \kappa (\lambda y_i)^{\kappa -1} \exp\{-(\lambda y_i ) ^\kappa \}$

How to find the score function of $(\kappa,\lambda)$

Does this mean we take the derivative of the log likelihood with respect to $\kappa$ then take the derivative of that result with respect to $\lambda$?

Or do we create a 2x1 vector where the top is derivative of the log likelihood with respect to $\kappa$ and the bottom is the derivative with respect to $\lambda$

Comment: What are theta1 and theta2 in your pdf?

Comment: I meant $\kappa$ and $\lambda$. I have made the changes.

Comment: The score function is defined as the partial derivative of the log-likelihood with respect to the parameters on which the distribution depends. So that would be the second option to go with. See that [it does indeed yield a $2\times 1$ (or $1\times 2$) vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_(statistics)#Definition)